# How to debug ruby plugins in SketchUp?

Tags: ruby, debugging, plugins, sketchup

The only tip I got to debug ruby plugins in SketchUp is the use of `puts`.

I tried to launch SketchUp this way: `sketchup.exe > log.txt 2> errors.txt`, but it only shows logs / errors from SketchUp app, not from its plugins.

Does anyone knows how to:

- Execute step by step inside SketchUp
- Get an execution stack when a plugin crashes SketchUp
- Any other idea that woul be helpfull to debug ruby plugins in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** As of SketchUp 2014 you can use Ruby IDE's to step through Ruby code. Follow the instructions at this GitHub repository: https://github.com/SketchUp/sketchup-ruby-debugger
No more `puts` debugging!

---

TBD has written and released a bridge to debug SketchUp Ruby plugins: http://labs.plugins.ro/

That's probably what you're looking for. I haven't used it myself yet - so can't elaborate too much on it.

---

I often use a call to the WIN32 api to `OutputDebugString` which allows me to see the output (in DebugView) I send to it regardless if SU craches - and it doesn't slow down the execution as much as outputting lots of stuff to the SketchUp Ruby Console:
http://www.thomthom.net/software/sketchup/tt_lib2/doc/TT.html#debug-class_method

(I meant to give a direct link to the BitBucket source code, but the site is down a the moment. Repo: https://bitbucket.org/thomthom/tt-library-2/ )
EDIT: Site back online - direct link: https://bitbucket.org/thomthom/tt-library-2/src/tip/TT_Lib2/debug.rb?at=Version%202.8

One could also reroute `puts` to `OutputDebugString` if you wanted a quick catch all solution.

---

On a slight sidenote, there is also the Developers Tools utility released by the SketchUp team with an enhanced Ruby Console and unit test framework: https://github.com/SketchUp/sketchup-developer-tools

Comment: Great! these tools are going to help me a lot, code production is getting easier.

Comment: Hope it eases the work a little. I hope to see more tools. At last SketchUp BaseCamp (2012) it was a very interesting topic. There's a few people with tools they've created for internal use. I hope more will come out as open source. It sure was a topic of great interest.

Comment: I forgot to add that I used DebugView to catch the output from `OutputDebugString`.

Answer (score 3):

SketchUp released an open source debugger for the SketchUp Ruby API on April 15th, 2014:

https://github.com/SketchUp/sketchup-ruby-debugger

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SketchUp folks released a new unit testing framework in October 2014. I've not tried using it yet, but will give it a shot and report back with what I find:

https://github.com/SketchUp/testup-2